Definition of Chow quotient
I am reading  M. M. Kapranov's paper "Chow quotients of Grassmannians. I." (English) in Sergej Gelfand (ed.) et al., I. M. Gelfand seminar. Part 2: Papers of the Gelfand seminar in functional analysis held at Moscow University, Russia, September 1993. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society, Advances in Soviet Mathematics 16(2), 29-110 (1993), MR1237834, Zbl 0811.14043. In the §0.1.1 of the paper it is written (here $\mathsf H$ is an algebraic group acting on a complex projective variety $X$):

For any point $x \in X$ we consider the orbit closure $\overline{H\cdot x}$ which is a compact subvariety in $X$.
For some sufficiently small Zariski open subset $U ⊂ X$ of
”generic” points all these varieties have the same dimension, say, $r$ and represent the same homology class $\delta \in H_{2r}(X, Z)$.

Why does such $U$ exist?

Welcome new contributor.  Assume that $X$ is integral, for simplicity.  Denote the action morphism by $$\mu:H\times X \to X.$$  Denote by $\Psi$ the product morphism $$(\mu,\text{pr}_2):H\times X \to X\times X.$$ Denote by $Y$ the Zariski closure of $\Psi(H\times X)$ inside $X\times X$.  Denote by $Z$ the Zariski closure of $Y\setminus \Psi(H\times X)$.
The projection $\text{pr}_2$ restricts to a dominant morphism from $Y$ to $X$, and it restricts to a morphism from $Z$ to $X$.  By Grothendieck's Generic Flatness / Freeness Theorem, the maximal open subscheme $U$ of $X$ over which these two morphisms are both flat is a dense open subscheme of $X$.  By considering generic fibers, the relative dimension of $Y$ over $X$ is pure of some dimension $n$, and every irreducible component of $Z$ that dominates $U$ has relative dimension strictly smaller than $n$.  Thus, for every point $p$ of $U$, the geometric fiber of $Z$ in the geometric fiber of $Y$ is nowhere dense, i.e., the geometric fiber of $Y$ over each point $p$ equals the closure of the $\mu$-image of $H\times \{p\}$ in $X$.
Since $Y$ is flat over the connected scheme $U$, the cycle classes of fibers of $Y$ over points of $U$ are algebraically equivalent cycles in $X$, hence homologically equivalent cycles in $X$.  Thus, the restriction of $Y$ over $U$ gives a "nice" family of cycles that defines a morphism from $U$ to the Chow scheme of $X$ (a la Angeniol and Rydh).  In fact, the maximal open subscheme of $X$ on which this morphism is regular is typically strictly larger than $U$, since a "nice" family of cycles need not be flat.
